# FFMPEG start and duration in FPS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Is it possible to set the -ss and -t flags in FFMPEG in frames?

I am building a simple video trimmer in PHP with FFMPEG and have been using PHP-FFMPEG to extract screen grabs etc and it works entirely in frames. Also my script requires that I add and subtract variable amounts of time to the start and end of the vid which is so much easier to do in FPS. PHP-FFMPEG tells me the fps of the vid, so I can accurately pinpoint frames as required.

Alternatively does anyone know of a nice little script for converting frames to HH:MM:SS.xx format at all? I can just use that instead. My Google attempts have been fruitless so far, and my attempt at it has got me rather stressed.

Comment: OK, so the converting to HH:MM:SS.xx bit is simple enough, i've just been having a brain freeze -  floor(frames / FPS) gives me the seconds, and I can work out the modulus of that too to give me the odd frames left over - I've been staring at this code for too long I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert to HH:MM:SS.xx format.

The `-t` and `-ss` flags for FFmpeg accept the number of seconds (including decimal) as well as HH:MM:SS.xx format.  From [the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> **`-ss position (input/output)`**
>   When used as an input option (before `-i`), seeks in this input file to `position`. When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach `position`. This is slower, but more accurate.
>
> ***position*** may be either in seconds or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.

So just do frames/frames per second and you've got your input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `-ss` but you can use `-vframes` instead of `-t` to specify exact number of video frames.